# Implement POSIX fork in Java and keep a copy of data

Tags: java, c, fork, posix

I want to port some multi-process C codes to Java but not sure what should be the right design.

The C code implements an in-memory key-value cache supporting snapshot periodically, similar to Redis. When the memory data is about to snapshot, it forks the current process, so the current process can keep serving the clients and the child process can snapshot with a copy of the in-memory data.

When I try to port these codes to Java, I found out that there is no POSIX `fork()` equivalent. `Runtime.exec()` or `ProcessBuilder` does not offer a copy of the data of the current process, and copying data by ourselves is obviously a bad idea since it is not a copy-on-write.

The traditional way to achieve concurrency is via thread. However, this requires synchronization for key-value pairs during the snapshot, so I am a little bit concerned about the performance. But I am not sure if my concern about the performance is valid or not.

I thought of persisting the command rather than the data, and translate each command to the idempotent version before writing them to disk, so the snapshot no longer needs synchronization, which is similar to Write-Ahead log in Zookeeper. However, this may be a worse idea because we are requiring a disk write for each command in an in-memory database, where speed is the first priority.

Is there a good way to implement the above feature in Java: snapshot concurrently and efficiently for in-memory data? Any advice would be appreciated!

Comment: If you’re asking whether you can copy every piece of heap data for an entire Java program, the answer is no.  You can, however, share immutable objects between threads with little to no performance concerns.

Comment: @VGR Thanks, I know I should not do that. Maybe i should modify my last paragraph to: can we do the snapshot concurrently in a lock-free way in java?

Comment: You could use the cache as a read-only 'secondary' cache during the snapshot process, and start a new 'primary' cache where new values are put. This would then be copied to the old cache after snapshots are complete.

Comment: Also, what consistency properties does the snapshot need? If some but not all of the new entries which are calculated during the snapshot end up in the snapshot, does that mean you have an inconsistent snapshot?

Comment: @tgdavies Thanks this solution sounds good to me! This product does not require strong consistency, what you describe is definitely enough.

Comment: You can fork via JNI: http://jnicookbook.owsiak.org/recipe-no-029/ - I am not sure whether this is what you are looking for.